# Converting / Casting data types to Data type

Tags: swift

The MultipeerConnectivity framework sends data between connected peers using the Data data type. There are online tutorials covering how to convert simple data types such as String into a Data object, which can then be passed to:

```
MCSession.send(data: Data, toPeers: [MCPeerID], with: MCSessionDataMode)
```

or

```
MCSession.sendResource(at: URL, withName: String, toPeer: MCPeerID, withCompletionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)?)
```

As an example, I have tried to send a PHAssetCollection (from the PhotoKit framework), simply passing in this object to the MCSession.send(data: collection ....) but it returns an error that it is not of "Data" type.

```
MCSession.send(collection, toPeers: [peers], with: MCSessionDataMode.reliable)
```

The error is within Xcode, as I cannot find a way to convert my data types into the expected Data data type.

Comment: You just cannot send a `PHAssetCollection`.

Comment: Instead of sending a `PHAssetCollection`, you should consider sending the image data (or whatever data you want) that you fetch from the collection.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks, the intention was to send copies of PHAssetCollections from connected devices to a single device, allowing the single device to perform calculations / processing of multiple collections on this device using native frameworks. The end result would be to display a subset of images, which would then be requested individually based on the processing.

Comment: What about having the single device send queries to the other devices, and have the other devices do the processing, then send the resulting images back to the single device?